# A button that updates the stock and interacts with React props

Tags: api, user-interface, reactjs

[image]

I am a newbie in the React field and I need some conceptual help. I just want that button to update the API instantly when the button is pressed(every click should decrease the stock by 1). The information on the number of items available comes from the API. How can I do that?

That's my buy() method

```
  buy(item){
    this.setState({
      total: this.state.total + parseFloat(item),
      amount: this.state.amount + 1
    })

  }

  render(){
    const allProducts = this.state.products.map((product, i) =>
      {return <ShopItem key = {i} item = {product} buyMethod = {this.buy.bind(this)}/>
    })

    return(
      <div className = "shop">
      <Link to = 'shop/payment'>PAY</Link>
      <p>Total to pay:{this.state.total}</p>
      <p>You have bought {this.state.amount} items</p> 
      {allProducts}
      </div>
      )
  }
}
```

and the buy handler in the shopItem component

```
onHandleBuy(event){
    event.preventDefault()
    this.props.buyMethod(this.props.item.price)
    if(this.props.item.stock == 0){
      <p className = "shop">No more items available</p>
    }else{
      this.props.stock - 1
    }
  }

  stockFormat () {
    let output
    if (this.props.item.stock == 0) {
      output = <p className = "shop">No more items available</p>
    } else {
      output = <p>{this.props.item.stock} items left </p>
    }
    return output
  }

  stockFormatButton() {
    let button
    if (this.props.item.stock == 0) {
      button = <p className = "shop">Out of stock</p>
    } else {
      button = <button onClick = {this.onHandleBuy.bind(this)}>BUY</button>
    }
    return button

  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div className = "product">
      <img src = {this.props.item.url} />
      {this.stockFormat()}
      {this.stockFormatButton()}
      </div>
      )
  }
```

Hope it's not too much code

Comment: You should add a code snippet  & your attempt .

Comment: done! I just thought that it might not be that relevant

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the item object that is passed down to the ShopItem component is coming from an array of products held in the state of the parent component. This item.stock value is where the number is coming from, right? So when you're decrementing its value, you need to update that item value in the parent component's state. You're trying to modify the prop itself:
`else { this.props.stock - 1 }`

In React, all components must be pure in regards to their props. In other words, a component cannot alter its own props.

You should take a similar approach as you have with your buyMethod. Include some sort of decrement in the `buy` function of the parent component, and then pass down those updated values as props to your ShopItem component.